# Dual boot Mac - void warranty

Tags: macos, software, warranty

For work reasons I have to dual boot windows 7 in my mac. Does doing so voids my warranty?

Comment: Nooooo it doesn't. They created Bootcamp for this purpose. Who told you that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your warranty will not be voided, as this does not violate any Apple agreements.

Comment: What about the performance factor when I run windows

Comment: I find that an Apple computer runs Windows better than any other run-of-the-mill PC. You will get high performance.

Comment: @jason no, I don't agree. You'll get better perf with a PC of this price. But it'll still be good

Comment: @Thomas MacBook Air's have been called the best laptop to run windows.

Comment: @JashJacob yeah, 2 years ago. See the `YOGA 3 Pro`... The MBA is shitty compared to it...